# dygraph custom labeling on mouseover fails

Tags: r, graph, dygraphs

I am trying to set the text at the top of my graph to a custom value, based on the mouseover point on the x axis. I thought I followed the [example](http://dygraphs.com/per-axis.html) on the dygraph site correctly. Can someone explain how to do it correctly using my example below?

Error:

```
Error in dygraph(df, { : object 'axes' not found
```

My code:

```
library(quantmod)
data<-getSymbols("USD/EUR",src="oanda",env=NULL)
df<-as.data.frame(data)

df2<-data.frame(row.names(df))
df2$output<-sample(0:10,length(row.names(df)),replace=T)

library(dygraphs)
#dygraph(df)

dygraph(df, {
    axes:{
        x:{
            valueFormatter: function(dte){
                #how to return df2$output with the same date as the date from df that just got passed in? 
                return(???)
            }
        }   
    }   
})
```

function to take in date and return the correct string as a label (in R):

```
#pass in date to this function
retString<-function(dateFromDygraph){
 #returns the data
} #I can write this, I just dont know how to use it in the dygraph code you wrote
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps you a bit. Must say it requires knowledge of both R and JavaScript.

First of all, Answering to your first question. There is a big difference between R and JavaScript as far as syntax is concerned.

The Code that you mentioned is a JavaScript Code. I am talking about this:

```
{
    axes:{
        x:{
            valueFormatter: function(dte){
            #how to return df2$output with the same date as the date from df that just got passed in? 
                return(???)
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

This code can not be used directly in R. That's why you are getting the error.

**Solution to first Problem:**

If you do some searching work on `dygraphs` package, you will find a function `dyAxis` which is used to manipulate the axes details.

In that, you can directly pass on the Javascript Code related to `axisLabelFormatter` and `valueFormatter`  as a character string.

**Solution to your second Problem:**

As far as second problem is concerned, you may give a try to this code:

```
## 1:nrow(df) is column binded for a reason. Later, it will be used for finding the Date and the Output to be selected
g <- dygraph(data.frame(1:nrow(df),df$USD.EUR))

## Create the JavaScript Array for Date and Output and access it using the index specified earlier
dyAxis(g,'x',axisLabelFormatter = paste0('function(x){
    var dates = [',paste(paste0("'",df2[['row.names.df.']],"'"),collapse=','),'];

    return dates[x - 1];
}'),valueFormatter = paste0('function(x){
    var out = [',paste(df2$output,collapse=','),'];

    return out[x - 1];
}'))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, but Im having trouble with the Second Problem solution. Is it possible to pass the current date to a function that will return the correct answer? I can write the function, I just dont know how to pass the date to a custom function?

Comment: I updated my post with a simple function. If it isnt possible that fine, I just wanted to know for sure.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what that function does exactly with an example?

Comment: I added more text to my question. Does that help?

Comment: Do you want the function to return the data plotted on y axis for the date passed in as a parameter in the function?

Comment: No, the function will pull data from somewhere else. It will take in the date being hovered over and return a string to be displayed on the graph. I can write the function, Im just not sure how to pass the date to my function using dygraph

Comment: I think you will be required to build a function similar to what I did in `axisLabelFormatter` code. You may first get the value of X axis parameter and then get the date from it.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on that and post it once I get it completed.